# CakePHP modify skel for plugins

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

Is it possible to modify the skeleton structure for a plugin?

I've found in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html) and it says how to change the skel for baking a ***project*** using

```
cake bake project -skel Console/Templates/skel
```

However, what I want is to be able to bake a ***plugin***, something like:

```
cake bake plugin Demo -skel Console/Templates/demo_skel
```

and be able to provide custom css/javascripts/views/etc, but just for my plugin, not the whole app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No

Unfortunately not, the plugin task [does not use a template](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Console/Command/Task/PluginTask.php#L92), it just uses a hard coded array to generate the basic plugin structure.

### But maybe soon

That said [about a year ago](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/feature/plugin-template/) (so long ago? Oh the shame). I started working on providing exactly that, and apparently forgot about it. So perhaps in the next minor release it will be available.